# dropdownlist showing as undefined in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to add dropdown's by way of using the custom editor in my grid, and the dropdowns are showing as undefined

[image: Catalogs as undefined]

When I click on the undefined, the dropdown appears, and I can select a value from it, but once I click on another undefined dropdown, then it goes back to being undefined, but doesn't lose the selected value.

I have no idea why the dropdowns are showing as undefined and won't keep its selected value visible

```js
var datasource = [{
    "CatalogID": 1,
    "Catalog": "Free"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 2,
    "Catalog": "Discount"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 3,
    "Catalog": "Regular"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 4,
    "Catalog": "Holiday"
  }
];

const DEFAULT_AREA_NAME = "1";

$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadCatalogsGrid();
});

function LoadCatalogsGrid() {
  $("#Grid").empty();
  $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: false,
    height: 700,
    columns: [{
      field: "RoomName",
      title: "Room Name",
      width: "120px",
      template: "<div >#=RoomName #</div>"
    }, {
      title: "Catalog",
      field: "Catalog",
      template: '#=Catalog.CatalogName#',
      width: "200px",
      editable: false,
      editor: catalogDropDownEditor
    }],
    editable: {
      mode: "incell",
      confirmation: false
    },
    dataSource: {
      data: [{
          RoomName: "Living Room",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Kitchen",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Master Bedroom",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Mud Room",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Garage",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        }
      ],
      //schema: {
      //    model: {
      //        fields: {
      //            RoomName: { nullable: true, editable: true },
      //            AreaName: { nullable: true, editable: true },
      //            Catalog: { editable: false },
      //        }
      //    }
      //}
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {

    }
  });
}

function catalogDropDownEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "Catalog",
      dataValueField: "CatalogID",
      dataSource: {
        data: datasource
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="GridWrapper">
  <div id="Grid">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't have an object like `Catalog.CatalogName`. `Catalog` in your data is just an empty string. You have to check if the property is valid to be shown in the template(e.g. `template: '#=(data.CatalogDescription || "")#'`) and after changing the dropdown value, you have to set the value to the model(as well it's description):

```
change: function() {
    options.model[options.field] = this.select();
    options.model[options.field + 'Description'] = this.text();
}
```

Take a look at your updated snippet below:

```js
var datasource = [{
    "CatalogID": 1,
    "Catalog": "Free"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 2,
    "Catalog": "Discount"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 3,
    "Catalog": "Regular"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 4,
    "Catalog": "Holiday"
  }
];

const DEFAULT_AREA_NAME = "1";

$(document).ready(function() {
  LoadCatalogsGrid();
});

function LoadCatalogsGrid() {
  $("#Grid").empty();
  $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: false,
    height: 700,
    columns: [{
      field: "RoomName",
      title: "Room Name",
      width: "120px",
      template: "<div >#=RoomName #</div>"
    }, {
      title: "Catalog",
      field: "Catalog",
      template: '#=(data.CatalogDescription || "")#',
      width: "200px",
      editable: false,
      editor: catalogDropDownEditor
    }],
    editable: {
      mode: "incell",
      confirmation: false
    },
    dataSource: {
      data: [{
          RoomName: "Living Room",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Kitchen",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Master Bedroom",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Mud Room",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        },
        {
          RoomName: "Garage",
          AreaName: DEFAULT_AREA_NAME,
          Catalog: ""
        }
      ],
      //schema: {
      //    model: {
      //        fields: {
      //            RoomName: { nullable: true, editable: true },
      //            AreaName: { nullable: true, editable: true },
      //            Catalog: { editable: false },
      //        }
      //    }
      //}
    },
    dataBound: function(e) {

    }
  });
}

function catalogDropDownEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "Catalog",
      dataValueField: "CatalogID",
      value: options.model[options.field],
      dataSource: {
        data: datasource
      },
      change: function() {
          options.model[options.field] = this.select();
          options.model[options.field + 'Description'] = this.text();
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="GridWrapper">
  <div id="Grid">

  </div>
</div>
```